Join two tables with dates and list each changes in the range of dates
I have two tables one for Employee's Name P_NAMES this table contains a historical record of employees if they change their names since they were hired "Effective Date" some have one row some have 4  or 6 rows depending how many times they changed their name.
I have another table for Employee History that contains their job code their supervisor and their title etc.  P_HIST
I want to show the employee history with the actual name at that time "Effective Date".  Not sure if I should create a new table or just a simple join.  Ideally I can get this data by using Effective date between but that would have to be a manual query.
Here is an example
SELECT 
    a.[EMPLID],
    a.[EFFDT],
    a.[NAME]
FROM
    [P_NAMES] a

enter image description here
Here is the Employee History
SELECT 
    b.EMPLID,
    b.NAME,
    b.EFFDT
FROM 
    [P_HIST] b

enter image description here
I could get this data if I write a simple query like this
Select .
.
.
where
.
and EFFDT   between 
  -- '2008-08-04 00:00:00.000' and '2011-12-01 00:00:00.000'
  --'2011-12-02 00:00:00.000' and '2017-04-05 00:00:00.000'
   '2017-04-06 00:00:00.000' and '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000'

the end result would look like this
enter image description here
Any ideas?
I tried this, for each date
SELECT 
    a.[EMPLID],
    a.[EFFDT],
    b.[EFFDT],
    b.[NAME]
FROM 
    [P_NAMES] a, [P_HIST] b
WHERE  
    a.[EMPLID] = b.[EMPLID]
    AND b.EFFDT BETWEEN '2017-04-06 00:00:00.000' AND '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000'

enter image description here

Instead of posting images of query results you should post table definitions (as create statements), and sample data as insert statements.

Bad habits to kick: using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years ago!) and its use is discouraged

Probably worth reading this one too about using meaningful alias names so you don't pull your hair out when you have more than a couple tables. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

To select the best matching row from the P_NAMES table for each row of the P_HIST table, you can use the CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...) technique.
SELECT
    PH.EMPLID,
    PH.NAME AS DepartmentName,
    PH.EFFDT,
    N.NAME AS EmployeeName,
    N.EFFDT AS NameEffectiveDate
FROM P_HIST PH
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 PN.*
    FROM P_NAMES PN
    WHERE PN.EMPLID = PH.EMPLID
    AND PN.EFFDT <= PH.EFFDT
    ORDER BY PN.EFFDT DESC
) N

A CROSS APPLY is like a join to a subselect that lets you select the matching rows (based on EMPLID), filter that data further (based on EFFDT), define a preference rule (ORDER BY PN.EFFDT DESC), and finally pick the best match (TOP 1).
If there is a chance that there will be no matching row satisfying the filter criteria, you could instead use an OUTER APPLY, which behaves similar to a LEFT JOIN.
Sample results (with some extra test data):



EMPLID
JobCode
JobEffectiveDate
EmployeeName
NameEffectiveDate




8704
Job A
2008-08-04
Smith Jane
2008-08-04


8704
Job B
2009-04-04
Smith Jane
2008-08-04


8704
Job C
2009-09-28
Smith Jane
2008-08-04


8704
Job D
2012-03-03
Jones Jane
2011-12-02


8704
Job F
2012-06-25
Jones Jane
2011-12-02


8704
Job G
2013-03-04
Jones Jane
2011-12-02


8704
Job H
2019-02-09
Doe Jane
2017-04-06


8704
Job I
2020-10-17
Doe Jane
2017-04-06


...
...
...
...
...


9999
Job W
2024-01-01
Alpha
2024-01-01


9999
Job X
2024-01-31
Alpha
2024-01-01


9999
Job Y
2024-02-01
Bravo
2024-02-01


9999
Job Z
2024-07-11
Charlie
2024-03-01



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

I think I found a solution not sure but it sure gets me 90% going if I do this
WITH ranked_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        [EMPLID],
        [EFFDT],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EMPLID] ORDER BY [EFFDT]) AS row_num,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [EMPLID]) AS total_rows
    FROM 
        [PS_NAMES]
    
)

and then do a JOIN based on this
SELECT
    rd.[EMPLID],
    rd.[EFFDT],
    COALESCE(
        lag(rd.[EFFDT]) OVER (PARTITION BY rd.[EMPLID] ORDER BY rd.[EFFDT] DESC),
        '9999-12-31'  -- Set to system date if it's the first row or the only row for that employee
    ) AS previous_date
FROM
    ranked_dates rd
   ..
..

with P_HIST
